# Which is the best recommended CU patch(Stable one) should be applied to newly created SP2013 Farm before start using it?

Tags: cumulative-update

We have setup the new SharePoint 2013 server  Farm.It consist of 1 App Server,1 web server & 1 Database server.

Currently it is at SharePoint 2013 SP1 patch level.

Which is the best recommended CU patch(Stable one) should be applied to this newly created SP2013 Farm before start using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good recommendation is to always be one CU behind the current release for production environments to avoid issues that may be introduced by a new CU. I would treat a Service Pack the same way in that you would wait until a CU is released after the Service Pack before proceeding.

So, currently for SharePoint 2013 environment, you should install November 2016 CU.

[SharePoint server 2013 November 2016 CU](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54214)

Comment: Thanks Gautam!!Are there  any known issues reported for this November 2016 CU?

Comment: @SaurabhJawalekar - there are no known issues reported for November 2016 CU. But it would be a good idea to install it on a dev/staging environment first before installing on production. [November 2016 CU] (https://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Regressions/sp2013nov2016cu.aspx)